# DropDown default selection

Tags: orbeon

I have an Orbeon Form containing a DropDown Menu. This one is populated (all country names) by an action at Form Load from an SQL Datasource. Both Label and Value are populated.

How to have a default value selected instead of the [Select...] ? In this case, I know the Value of the default item to be selected.

Comment: Hi. Could you clarify how you "know" the default value - is it a separate SQL lookup? Also, are your values "human readable" or an ID of some sort (perhaps ISO country codes)? Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019006/xforms-set-default-selection-in-dropdown-in-binding

Comment: Hi. The data in the "country" table will not change that frequently, and I want the country "Switzerland" be selected by default in my drop-down. This record has the primary key 'CHE' in the database, and this key is the Value of the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to include the value in the fr-form-instance in the model.

For example:

```
<xf:instance id="fr-form-instance">
    <form>
        <section-1>
            <country>CHE</country>
        </section-1>
    </form>
</xf:instance>
```

There are other ways, as discussed at [XForms: set default selection in dropdown in binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019006/xforms-set-default-selection-in-dropdown-in-binding)

Regards

jez